# Resharper AltEnter button not appear

Tags: visual-studio, resharper, visual-studio-2015

Visual Studio 2015, not RC.
Resharper 9

Sometimes AltEnter (QuickFix) button works fine, but sometimes I lose it and can't find it while I don't restart PC/VS/etc or make something like magic. I try everything: disable extensions, restart visual studio, restart PC. I do not want reset visual studio, because I have a lot of settings. Actually, I don't know how I can find error in showing this button, and any idea will be great.

Comment: Instead of asking [so] you may have better luck asking over [JetBrains discussion forums](https://devnet.jetbrains.com/community/resharper/resharper_community?view=discussions)